# How to read temperature with STM32F103C8T6?

Tags: stm32, temperature, programming, thermistor, board

How can I read the temperature using an NTC thermistor with an STM32F103C8T6 board??

Comment: The processor you're using has an internal temperature sensor attached to one of the ADC channels you could use too.

Comment: @Colin  What if he wants to read the temperature somewhere else other than the processor?

Comment: He is free to do so, it was intended to be a useful hint in case he was unaware, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pullup resistor with the thermistor to make a voltage divider. The resulting voltage goes to an ADC input on the processor.

Write some code that reads the ADC value and calculates the equivalent temperature. Don't forget that a thermistor's response is nonlinear.